# I am not able to put the functon, please help me to understand

Tags: formula

Filed name is "Staff Designation" and there is three name in there "Executive,Junior,Trainees"... and with using of validation i want to Put in another field name is " Pay". i.e, If i choose Executive then in next field "Pay" field must not less than >50000,like that Junior max pay>30000, and Trainees max pay> 20000.

I have one more question i.e., When I put only "Staff_Designation__c, 'Executive'" and If i didn't mention any value in "Executive_Max_Pay__c" field, when next I click on save button then it save the lead. my question is when if I choose "Staff_Designation__c" Executive and the user must have to enter the value above 50000. "Show the error, "If there is not mention any value in the field when the "Executive_Max_Pay__c" is blank.

I wrote this function:

```
If(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Executive'),Executive_Max_Pay__c >=50000,null) || If(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Juniors Executive'),Executive_Max_Pay__c >=30000,null) || If(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Trainees'),Executive_Max_Pay__c >=10000,null)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is it exactly that you want? A validation formula? In that case, @Ratan 's answer seem's good. Or is it a new calculated field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Staff_Designation__c` is a picklist

Suppose field API names  `Staff_Designation__c` and  `Pay__c`

Validation rule

```
If(AND(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Executive'), Pay__c < 5000), true,
   If(AND(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Junior'), Pay__c > 30000), true,
    If( AND(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Trainees '), Pay__c > 20000), true, false)
   )
)
```

---

### Updates

```
OR(ISNULL(Executive_Max_Pay__c), 
    If(AND(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Executive'), Executive_Max_Pay__c < 5000), true,
       If(AND(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Junior'), Executive_Max_Pay__c > 30000), true,
        If( AND(ISPICKVAL(Staff_Designation__c, 'Trainees '), Executive_Max_Pay__c > 20000), true, false)
       )
    )
)
```